# Error code: attempt to call a nil value <local 'cb'>

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto

Attempting to call a nil value `local 'cb'`

```
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if(Users)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    else
        cb(nil)
    end
end)
```

Comment: What programming environment you are working in?  Is it a script for GTA game series?

Comment: `cb(nil)` is exactly the same as `cb()`. Either way, the parameter passed is `nil`. Without more context, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: yes this is for gta series I will post all the code

Comment: AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if(Users)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb()
        end
    else
        cb()
    end
end)

Comment: If `cb` is `nil` then you should not call `cb` (because the callback is not defined by the invoker).  Replace `if(Users)then` with `if(Users and cb)then`